# Drag and drop with dataTransfer between windows possible for touch devices?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, touch, data-transfer-objects

I'm a bit surprised - and maybe I'm just searching for the wrong terms - but to me it currently looks like you can't have drag and drop with data transfer on touch devices, is that true?

At least all I find is libraries like [interact.js](https://interactjs.io/) or [draggable](https://shopify.github.io/draggable/examples/unique-dropzone.html) making drag & drop *inside* a browser easier and consistent among different browsers and devices but they don't support data transfer. For data transfer you use the [Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) which seems to not support touch devices.

[This article](https://www.horuskol.net/blog/2020-08-15/drag-and-drop-elements-on-touch-devices/) seems to suggest this, too. Though it's old enough to keep up the hope that things have changed..

Am I missing something?

And in case I want drag and drop for item movement and data transfer for mouse *and* touch devices - would I have to implement for both interdependently?

Answer (score 0):

I found this repository on github:

https://github.com/Bernardo-Castilho/dragdroptouch

Seems nice if it works as advertised. I tested it on Android 12 with the stock browser and it worked. Then I tested it on iOS 12, which is only 4 years old, in Safari and it didn't work.

This is going to be difficult. Support will still be patchy. I also don't quite understand what you mean by "datatransfer between windows". You mean drag and drop between browser windows?

Comment: I mean data transfer using the `dataTransfer` attribute of drag events which allow you to drag text and files out of the browser (to e.g. a file browser, text editor, etc)

Comment: @frans OK, I understand. Never used that myself. Is the above link useful? I don't think it does the "datatransfer" thing.

Comment: If it successfully unifies drag/drop on desktop and mobile devices it might really help me implement movement on both mobile and desktop devices. DataTransfer seems to be just impossible though